# Material UI Grid spacing mystery

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, react-bootstrap

Hi everyone and happy Friday! Hope all doing good. I am just here because I have some confusion with Material UI's Grid Spacing. I am using React with Material UI's Grid component API. And in this Grid Component, there is a spacing attribute specific to Material UI that is supposed to dictate the Grid items/containers. The issue that I am seeing is that there is spacing on the right side of the screen, while the left side does not have spacing. Its like a padding/margin going on at the right side of the page. I would like to eliminate that whitespace and have been reading the documentation but its a bit confusing to understand. Does anyone have a clue as to what it is? Please see my code:

```
<Grid container xs={12} justify="center" direction="row" spacing={16}>
        <Helmet>
          <title>Pokemon Wallet</title>
        </Helmet>
        <Hidden mdDown>
          <Grid item lg={3}>
            <PokeBox />
          </Grid>
        </Hidden>
        <Grid item xs={12} lg={9}>
          <Grid container spacing={16}>
            <PokeSummary />
          </Grid>
          <Grid container spacing={16}>
            <PokeOverview />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Hidden lgUp>
          <div className={classes.floatingAddAccount}>
            <AddPokemon floatingAddAccount />
          </div>
        </Hidden>
      </Grid>));
```

Comment: Please create a Stackblitz or Codesandbox version of your code for people to debug.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you manage to fix it?